# How can I add conditions to the display of certain elements of a ZSH prompt?

Tags: python, themes, virtualenv, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm customizing my ZSH theme and I'm having some problems. To start with, I want some elements of my prompt to be displayed only when git and/or (my virtual environment) are used.

example:
Here I have my neutral prompt.

```
╭─[Swidenn ⏾ Hades] ▶ ~/Documents/
╰─[2003]-$                                                            [10:00:00]
```

And here you can see that the git information has appeared between 2 square brackets.

```
╭─[Swidenn ⏾ Hades] ⟜[git:master]⊸ ▶ ~/Documents/
╰─[2003]-$                                                            [10:00:00]
```

Now I've activated a virtual environment.

```
╭─[Swidenn ⏾ Hades] ⟜[git:master]⊸ [venv] ▶ ~/Documents/
╰─[2003]-$                                                            [10:00:00]
```

My problem is this: I'd like to display my virtual environment in the square brackets next to my git, like this:

```
╭─[Swidenn ⏾ Hades] ⟜[git:master env:venv]⊸ ▶ ~/Documents/
╰─[2003]-$                                                            [10:00:00]
```

All without impacting my neutral prompt.

My prompts are as follows:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[green]%}╭─[%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[white]%}Swidenn %{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[green]%}⚡%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[white]%}%M%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[green]%}]$(git_prompt_info) $(virtualenv_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[green]%}▷ %{$reset_color%}%{$fg[white]%}%~
%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[green]%}╰─[%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[white]%}%!%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[green]%}]-> '

RPROMPT='%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[white]%}%D{[%H:%M:%S]}'
```

I've tried using these variables

```
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX=" ⟜[%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[white]%}git:%{$fg_bold[white]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[green]%}]⊸"
```

but I don't know what they're called, so it's difficult for me to find solutions.

Comment: Please review [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on "Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?"

Comment: For complex prompts, setting a `precmd` function and using the `psvar` array is usually the best option. There are some examples in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A9307265+precmd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem by using simple conditions directly in my theme file. Here is my code:

```bash
function neutral_prompt {
  echo "╭─[Swidenn ⚡ %M] ▷ %~
╰─[%!]-> "
}

function bracket_prompt {
  echo "╭─[Swidenn ⚡ %M] ⟜[$(git_prompt_info) $(virtualenv_prompt_info)]⊸ ▷ %~
╰─[%!]-> "
}

function final_prompt {
  if [[ $(git_prompt_info) == "" && $(virtualenv_prompt_info) == "" ]] ; then 
    prompt="$(neutral_prompt)"
  else
    prompt="$(bracket_prompt)"
  fi

PROMPT='$(final_prompt)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the output of a program (like /bin/pwd or date) in the prompt.
So write a small shell script, and bury the conditional in there.

---

You may find that
[starship](https://starship.rs)
is of interest.

Comment: OK, but is it possible to do this in the zsh theme file ? If so, do you have any idea of the variables to use?